SQL Server Reporting Services Subscription delivery options
I want to setup a SSRS Subscription that sends the output to a SharePoint folder.  When I put the SharePoint URL path in the Path(Delivery options - Windows File Share) it tells me not correct UNC format.  How do I get it to work?

Unless you are running in sharepoint mode, I don't think you can.  The work around is to have a gateway setup and then use power automate to copy any files in local shared to sharepoint point site
